# Twitter image integration

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter

My app tweets in the following way:

```
-(IBAction)TweetMethod:(id)sender{

tweetView = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
TWTweetComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler
completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result)
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Twitter Result: canceled");
            break;
        case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone:
            NSLog(@"Twitter Result: sent");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Twitter Result: default"); break;
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; };
[tweetView setCompletionHandler:completionHandler]; 

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"Twitter.com"];


UIButton *button = (UIButton*) sender;

for (UITextView *text in messagetext) 
{

    for (UITextView *name in messagename) 
    {


    if ([text isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]] && text.tag == button.tag && text.tag== name.tag)
    {

             [tweetView setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Event name: %@. Download the app to check out the full details, including location, at: ", name.text]];
    }

   }

}


[tweetView addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"smallIcon 144 ipad.png"]];
[tweetView addURL:url];
[self presentModalViewController:tweetView animated:YES];

}
```

I noticed that if I keep this line:

```
[tweetView addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"smallIcon 144 ipad.png"]];
```

an image appears, but the blue button tweet is off, so I can't tweet, while if I remove the line, there is no image, and i can tweet. why??

Answer (score 0):

Twitter has a 140-character-limit! The tweet probably gets too long with that image. What does addImage/addURL return? If it returns NO the tweet is too long.

Another reason could be that you do not check `[TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]`. The user must have set up at least one twitter account in the settings.

Comment: What do you mean, an image is not text!! And by the way in the tweet view it says 10 characters left!!

Comment: The link to the image is appended as text (about 21 characters). Maybe the image must first be uploaded before you can press "tweet". So it can take some time if the image is large...

Comment: What do you mean, i dont understand. I have just deleted the woule text and the problem persists, by the way the image is 264dpi 300px by 300px

Comment: make sure you check `[TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]` first

Comment: did you check that addImage returns YES?

Comment: No, how do i do that? But the image appears... and i have 2 accounts set up so??